# Check a node has plaintext in jsoup?

Tags: java, html, css, dom, jsoup

I know the method Element.hasText() can check if a node has text on jsoup but include link text. I just want to check if it has plain text or not? Anyone can give me some solution? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cen use regex for this, here's an example:

```
final String html = "<p><span>spantext</span></p>"; // p-tag with no own text, but a child which has one
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

// Check if the 'p'-tag has own text
boolean hasText = doc.select("p").is("p:matchesOwn(^$)"); // --> true, p has no own text
```

if the element has some text this will return `false`:

```
final String html = "<p>owntext<span>spantext</span></p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

// Check if the 'p'-tag has own text
boolean hasText = doc.select("p").is("p:matchesOwn(^$)"); // --> false, p has some own text
```

Another solution:

```
public static boolean hasOwnText(Element element)
{
    return !element.ownText().isEmpty();
}
```

with the html and doc from above:

```
boolean hasText = hasOwnText(doc.select("p").first())
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) this answer.